# Reverse Engine of Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Greetings i have an existing database and i was going to build my application using ASP.NET Core, based on this [tutorial](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html), i've installed the packages for Entity Framework core, now i have to reverse my tables, so as tutorial said i used this command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=
(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=RFID;Trusted_Connection=True;" 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

However it keeps getting me this error:

> Invalid JSON file in C:\Users\user11\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\CoreOAS\src\CoreOAS\project.json

what should i do?

Comment: How about posting your project json, so we don't need our fortune telling skills? ;) Do you have imported the EFCore tools in your project.json?

Comment: @Tseng i think Sampath has fortune telling skill xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `comment` like below then above error will emit.So you have to remove that.

**Wrong :**

```
 // required for EF <--- this is the issue
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
```

**Correct way :**

```
 "buildOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true
      },
```

You can read more about it here : [**their (JSON) decision not to support comments**](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/24)

Comment: No problem :) I have updated the above post with `url`.Please read that.